# Is there a way to convert a list of strings to a list of ints in python?

Tags: python

So I have the following multidimensional list:

```
[['50 60 70 60'], 
 ['100 90 87 90'], 
 ['30 65 50 50'], 
 ['58 50 74 43']]
```

Is there anyway I can convert the strings to a list of ints, such as:

```
[[50, 60, 70, 60], 
 [100, 90, 87, 90], 
 [30, 65, 50, 50], 
 [58, 50, 74, 43]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested list comprehension where in the outer loop, you iterate over the sublists and in the inner loop, you cast each element of the outcome of `str.split` to type `int`:

```
out = [[int(x) for x in lst[0].split()] for lst in lsts]
```

Output:

```
[[50, 60, 70, 60], [100, 90, 87, 90], [30, 65, 50, 50], [58, 50, 74, 43]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
in_ = [['50 60 70 60'], 
 ['100 90 87 90'], 
 ['30 65 50 50'], 
 ['58 50 74 43']]

 out = []

 for list_ in in_:
     for nums in list_:
        buff = []
        buf = nums.split(' ')
        for num in buf:
            buff.append(int(num))
    out.append(buff)
    buff = []

print(out)
```